# Change app.config value of other project at runtime

Tags: c#, config, app-config

I have two projects under the same solution. 
I want to change the value of a project's app.config but I don' know how to do it

**Project A**

**Project B**

They are supposed to run as such : 
Project A is a codedUITest, and I want to change a value of it's configuration file.

This is how I have tried

```
string abc = @"absolutePath\app.config";
Configuration configuration =                     ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(abc);
configuration.AppSettings.Settings["areaCode"].Value = "new";
configuration.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

The project's app.config that I want to modify is a .dll (codedUiTestProject)

This is my node's structure :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="LogFilePath" value="" />
    <add key="areaCode" value="steamAccessDummy"/>
</appSettings>
```

I need some help, thanks !
Are there any other solutions ?

Comment: Since you need another configuration per project type, wouldn't it be more suited to transform the app.config at build time? There are some tools around, to modify the app.config per build configuration. For web it would be something like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx . For applications it's less trivial but a googly search will certainly give some results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);`